# Relationship between parameterized class with different type, Scala

Tags: scala, polymorphism

In Scala,
What is the relationship between parameterized class with different type?

For example,

```
class A[T]
```

What is the relationship between `A[Int] (or A[String])` and `A`?

and what is the relationship between  `A[Int]` and `A[String]` ?

I want to know, because I would like to do something like

```
case class A[T](v: T) { def print = println(v) }

def iter(s: Seq[A[???]]) = s.map(print) // What is the proper annotation of '???'

iter(Seq(A(1), A("Hello")) // 1 Hello
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what exactly you mean by "relationship"? What semantics are you looking for?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thanks for your comment, I added some example code that I would like to compile. Hope this can be helpful

Answer (score 1):

> What is the relationship between A[Int] and A?

`A` is a type constructor of kind `* → *`, and `A[Int]` is one of the possible results of apply a type (`Int`) to the type constructor `A`.

> What is the relationship between  A[Int] and A[String]?

The least upper bound between these two types is `A[_ >: String with Int]`, which can only be instantiated to `A[Any]` since it's the only super class of `String` and `Int`.

> What is the proper annotation of '???'

In your example that would be `Any`, or a type parameter you could add to your `def iter` that would itself be instantiated to `Any`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the exact answer that I wanted.
Now I realized that A is type constructor

Comment: `A` is not covariant in `T`, so `A[String]` is not a subtype of `A[Any]`.

Comment: @Jasper-M: indeed. But since `A("s"): A[Any]` I think I answered correctly the question, OP doesn't seem to care about variance.

Answer (score 1):

Types are related using [Variance](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html#variance).
To answer your question, Java's wildcards equivalent in Scala is [Existential types](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/). So you can specify something like this:

```
  def iter(s: Seq[A[_]]) = s.map(_.print)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
  def iter(s: Seq[A[T] forSome {type T}]) = s.map(_.print)
```

You can also specify bounds like below:

```
  def iter(s: Seq[A[_ <: CharSequence]]) = s.map(_.print)

  println(iter(Seq(A[StringBuilder](new StringBuilder("Test")), A[String]("Hello"))))
```

[Explicit type specified in constructors to avoid implicit conversion to required type CharSequence].
Note that the following would not compile though:

```
  def iter(s: Seq[A[CharSequence]]) = s.map(_.print)

  println(iter(Seq(A[StringBuilder](new StringBuilder("Test")), A[String]("Hello"))))
```

This is where variance specification in class would help:

```
case class A[+T](v: T) {
    def print = v
  }

  def iter(s: Seq[A[CharSequence]]) = s.map(_.print)

  println(iter(Seq(A[StringBuilder](new StringBuilder("Test")), A[String]("Hello"))))
```